# No os detected after Ubuntu install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

New to linux and trying to set up everything. So i had Win 7 before, i made a partition for win, it created smaller one for its data, around 100 mb. And a partition for linux that I will use later. So managed after a long trouble with booting from USB install linux, and now I don't have any OS, so writing this from Linux that I booted from usb.

What now, what info can i provide to help you help me. I have asrock p67 axtreme3, i5, 660, its uefi, i read that its important..

Help me to dual boot please

```
luj0@luj0-desktop:~$ sudo update grub
[sudo] password for luj0: 
sudo: update: command not found
luj0@luj0-desktop:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002dcc9

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2      1748723710  1953523711   102400001    5  Extended
/dev/sda3       307202048  1748721663   720759808    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4          206848   307202047   153497600   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda5      1748723712  1953523711   102400000   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8fe48fe4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   241414523   120706238    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2       241416190   488396799   123490305    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5       241416192   471861247   115222528   83  Linux
/dev/sdb6       471863296   488396799     8266752   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdc: 16.1 GB, 16106127360 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1958 cylinders, total 31457280 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *        2048    31457279    15727616    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

So this was my win 7 partition before `/dev/sda3`, I recognize it by amount of gb. Curently have 1 tb with 2 os installed, and one empty 250 gb drive for data only.. no os. Oh yeah and a usb containing windows is in, tried to repair startup but no go

UPD: I managed to boot onto Ubuntu, but here is the second problem I am facing: I don't see option to boot into Win 7. I did a boot repair as suggested on another response. So what can I do to have dual boot, or to find Windows?

Do note that I don't have cd drive so can't use recovery cd, and I don't have one ;)

Comment: The easiest and most foolproof way to dual boot is to use a separate hard drive and remove all other drives during install. Then just install normally. After it's up and running, add the original drive back and use your BIOS to select your OS. This remove any possibility of messing up your original OS, allows you to skip grub setup all together and when you have several drives setup like this then you can use a drive caddy to swap OSes as easily as if they were on USB drives. This won't help you much now though I'd imagine.

Comment: do you still have Win7 on your system, but cannot boot? I may have a solution

Comment: why dont you try to boot by usb `? set your USB by .iso file

Comment: I do not yet have personal experience making a UEFI dual boot system, but [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/193144/dual-boot-uefi-windows-7-and-ubuntu-12-04-both-64-bits-w7-entry-doesnt-appea) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have managed to boot to Ubuntu, open a terminal and try running

```
sudo update-grub
```

It will [automatically search for operating systems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) and may solve your problem.

If this does not help, please open a terminal and post the output of `sudo fdisk -l`. We can then make sure that you still have your Windows partition.

Comment: update grub didnt to anything, this shoud be my win 7 partition /dev/sda3 307202048 1748721663 720759808 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Comment: @user262433, use `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 0):

I have just posted an answer regarding the UEFI. Try to restart and boot to Bios. 
To enter Bios, its usually pressing F2,or F12 , or similar when you turn on the machine depends on your model.

Go to Bios menus looking for the word UEFI and change it to legacy. See if that brings the boot screen.