# Windows doesnt appear in grub but exists in legacy mode

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Im new to Linux and i faced a problem during dual boot windows and linux in separate disks.

In the grub menu windows doesnt appear and only ubuntu appears. But if i go to boot menu and change UEFI mode to Legacy mode then Windows starts automatically after reboot.

Comment: Ubuntu must have been installed in UEFI mode, while Windows is in legacy, in which case what you describe is the expected behavior. Not sure what's the question here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dual boot UEFI Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 (both 64 bits). W7 entry doesn't appear in GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193144/dual-boot-uefi-windows-7-and-ubuntu-12-04-both-64-bits-w7-entry-doesnt-appea)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert from EFI to BIOS boot mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360543/convert-from-efi-to-bios-boot-mode)

Answer (score 3):

Both / All OS's must be installed in same mode. So if Windows is allready installed in Legacy mode, Ubuntu must be too, for both to show up in GRUB menu. And visa versa.

Comment: Is there a way to detect windows in the grub without changing the modes?